# Stack Initialization Problem in Real Mode: How to Properly Initialize the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, stack-memory, bios

I am writing a simple boot loader in x86 assembly, here is the code for it :

```
org 0x7C00
section boot start=0x7C00


; initializing the stack 
mov ax,0xF000
mov ss,ax 

mov sp,0xFFFF
mov bp,0xFFFF




; loading the additional sectors 
mov ah,0x02
mov al,0x02    ; number of sectors
mov ch,0x00    ; cylinder 
mov cl,0x02    ; sector 2
mov dh,0x00    ; head 

; address = es*0x10 + bx
xor bx,bx  ; moving 0 to es 
mov ds,bx
mov es,bx    
mov bx,0x8000

int 0x13

jmp 0x8000

times 510-($-$$) db 0 

db 0x55, 0xaa     ; Ending the boot sector
```

the problem is that whenever I remove the stack initialization code the boot loader works just fine and the BIOS interrupts are executed, but when I add the code back in nothing happens and the interrupts don't work.

what am I doing wrong ?? and why is this happening ??

Comment: `0xF000` segment is a really bad place for stack, as that is the BIOS ROM usually :) Consult a [memory map](https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)). TL;DR: you likely want to stick to the low 640k that is below `0xA000` segment.

Comment: 0xF000 is the stack segment location not the stack pointer, I set the stack pointer to 0xFFFFF

Comment: Yes and that is bad. Also setting `sp` to an odd address is not recommended (although it works). Keep it aligned to 16 bits at least.

Comment: @Jester ok thank you, I will try changing the stack location, and I'll set what happens

Answer (score 2):

A common setting for a MBR boot ss:sp is to set them to 00000h:07c00h, so that the stack ends just before the start of the boot code.